# Linear algebra - computation with matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I'm sorry for the stupid question, can you help to understand how to move from the first row to the second one, which property of linear algebra has been used?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bunch of rewrites using $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$.

Comment: I see, thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As noted in a comment, the first line uses the fact that the inverse of a product is the product of the inverses in reverse order, $(ABC)^{-1}=C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}$ (which you can check by multiplying it out).